# Redux - handling really large state object

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a simple react + flask application.
I want to load some data (~10mb) when the user clicks a button, and then use this data.
Because two different components have to interact with this data, i thought ill save the data as a global state using redux.

What i basically have is two components:

1. have a button that calls an action to load the large data from the flask server (and save that data into the global redux state)
2. uses the data (from the global state)

Once i did that, i was getting "SerializableStateInvariantMiddleware took 509ms, which is more than the warning threshold of 32ms.", Which made me think this isnt the right way to do so.

What is the right way to handle something like that?
Should i keep a different smaller state (so i know the "load data" button was clicked), and read that state from the second component and only then load the data into a private state?
(check if the global state was changed and if it did, call an action and save the data in the private state?)

Comment: Use `lazy loading` or `Vitualized Data`

Answer (score 50):

I'll elaborate on the excellent answer by @phry.

Instead of configuring the ignored paths, you could just increase the timeouts:

```
const store = configureStore({
  // ...
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
    immutableCheck: { warnAfter: 128 },
    serializableCheck: { warnAfter: 128 },
  })
})
```

or turn off the checks altogether:

```
const store = configureStore({
  // ...
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
    immutableCheck: false,
    serializableCheck: false,
  })
})
```

Source: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware

Comment: This worked, but is it to have any performance impacts if we load 5 MB of data on load?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Any update on performance impacts?

Answer (score 26):

No, that's fine.
There are just the `SerializableStateInvariantMiddleware` and `ImmutableStateInvariantMiddleware` active in development mode that walk through all of that to check if everything is serializable and nothing was modified by accident.

With normal-sized states that is no problem, in your case it is obviously. But you can just disable these two middlewares for that path where you store that big chunk of data.

See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#customizing-the-included-middleware, https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/immutabilityMiddleware and https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware

So your configureStore would look like

```js
const store = configureStore({
  // ...
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
    immutableCheck: {

        // Ignore state paths, e.g. state for 'items':
        ignoredPaths: ['items.data']

    },
    serializableCheck: { ignoredPaths: ['some.nested.path'] }
  })
})
```

Comment: thanks!
just a small question, the data is stored in a redux global state, so how can i know what is the actual path of this data?

Comment: how would you get it out of global state without knowing that path?

Answer (score 3):

i went through the same issue down below solution check out documentation and you can see how i solved

```html
    export const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
        // Add the generated reducer as a specific top-level slice
        [MusicApi.reducerPath]: MusicApi.reducer,
      },
      // Adding the api middleware enables caching, invalidation, polling,
      // and other useful features of `rtk-query`.
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          immutableCheck: false,
          serializableCheck: false,
        }).concat(MusicApi.middleware),
    });
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-immutable-state-invariant
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

this script solved my problem

```
const store = configureStore({
        reducer: {cartItems},
        middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).